# JavaScript add 1 every one second with unexpected error

Tags: javascript

```
const setTimer = (n) => {
    var initNum = 1;
    const stopTimer= () => {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
    var myTimer = setInterval(() => {
        if (initNum <= n) {
            console.log(initNum);
            initNum ++;
        } else {
            stopTimer()
        }
    },1000)
}

console.log(setTimer(5));
```

In the console, I though it would print `1 2 3 4 5` every 1 second, however, I am getting `undefined 1 2 3 4 5`, does anyone can give a hint?

Comment: What do you think setTimer returns?

Answer (score 3):

You're logging the return value of `setTimer(5)`, which is `undefined.`